# Sharepoint - welcome menu username doesn't change colour on IE

Tags: internet-explorer, sharepoint

I hope you can help here.  I'd appreciate any responses.

I'm using Sharepoint 2010.  On IE11 the username on the welcome menu doesn't change to the correct colour.  It should be white, but stays dark blue.

When the pages load, the username briefly flashes white, then stays blue.  'Site Actions' is showing white.  All the menu items are showing correctly.
The welcome menu's down triangle *is* white but the username text is blue.

**The username is white when I load the same pages on Chrome.**
When I load the same page (same user account) in IE on a remote desktop session, the username displays correctly in white.

I've tried resetting IE and clearing the temp internet files/cache & restarted IE but it's still not showing the right colour.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**I've fixed this**: did a full reset > unticked Delete personal settings

now showing white.

*(talking to myself here - ;-D)